# Get last 3 months data with case statement

Tags: sql

I would like to create a derived column by using a case statement or any other better suggestions.

My ask needs to set a flag if the sale has started in the last 3 months as New Sale and also exclude forward order book sale eg: sales done to start in the future.

I have the below script but complete yet.

```sql
SELECT 
 SaleID, 
 SaleStartDate, 
 [Is New Move-In] =
CASE WHEN SaleStartDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())  THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'END
FROM [dbo].[Sale]
```

This is giving me the last 3 months but also sales in the future also which are not needed.

Comment: What's your dbms? could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: What is a *flange*?

Comment: `... WHERE SaleStartDate <= GETDATE()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 SaleID, 
 SaleStartDate, 
 [Is New Move-In] =
CASE WHEN SaleStartDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) AND SaleStartDate < GETDATE()
     THEN 'Yes'
     ELSE 'No'
     END
FROM [dbo].[Sale]
```